# xcode showing "is not on any development teams"

Tags: ios, xcode

I am assigned as a technical in users and roles!
[Image showing me as a technical](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZ6vg.png)
so when i was following other tutorials it gave me the error this account is not assigned to any developers team. 
[image]

Also when i am going into member center it's not showing me the option certificates,identifiers and profiles
[image]

what needs to be done to resolve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to have enterprise apple developer for that.check this link:
    https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/
    Its 99$ enrollment program.
    The iOS Developer Program provides a complete and integrated process for developing and distributing iOS apps on the App Store.

Comment: the person who add me as the technical is already using this program,do i need to enroll by $99?? @Pankti Patel

Comment: You can verify this link : https://developer.apple.com/programs/which-program/ , with the person who added you as technical. They might be using free account which will not have rights to distribute app. .(Option for certificates, Provisioning profile will not available for them.)

Comment: yes he is using a paid account,as he has already couple of apps hosted and live.

Comment: i am having same problem,, the person who add me as the technical is already using this program, do i need to enroll by $99?? what was the solution  ?  the person who added has to have Company/Organization enrollment or individual enrollment would suffice ?

Comment: @ntsh YES,,  IOS Company/Organization enrollment account is needed and Agent/Owner should also add me as a team member with admin/technical role..

Comment: Thanks @Dave I figured that out too by digging into the documentation. You need to be added in both iTunesConnect and Member Center.

Comment: @ntsh yeah.. it also a  required step .. i missed it. :)